# First echo missing when using bash -c over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, quotes

While debugging a script that runs various commands remotely, I noticed some problems getting output from `echo`.

I realize that the `bash -c` isn't necessary here, but it still has me wondering.

In my shell:

```sh
> bash -c "echo hello && echo hi"
hello
hi
```

But, if I bring SSH into the picture:

```sh
> ssh ${myhost} bash -c "echo hello && echo hi"

hi
```

Yet, `date` outputs, even though that first `echo` didn't:

```sh
> ssh ${myhost} bash -c "date && echo hi"
Thu Jun  3 21:15:26 UTC 2021
hi
```

What's going on here?

Comment: How about just `ssh ${myhost} "echo hello && echo hi"` ?

Comment: @PaulHodges yes, that works (mentioned that `bash -c` wasn't necessary in this example); I'm curious why using `bash -c` causes this behavior.

Comment: I suggest to add two `'`: `ssh ${myhost} 'bash -c "echo hello && echo hi"'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a command via `ssh` like this, it's parsed twice: first on the local computer (before it's passed to the `ssh` command as arguments), then again on the remote computer before it's actually executed. Each time it's parsed, the shell will apply *and remove* quotes and escapes. That means the double-quotes you have around the command get applied and removed by the local shell, before the command is sent to the remote shell. So what looks like this command:

```
bash -c "echo hello && echo hi"
```

Turns into this by the time the remote shell sees it:

```
bash -c echo hello && echo hi
```

...which is two separate commands, `bash -c echo hello` and `echo hi`. The second one, `echo hi`, works as you expect, but the first may not.

With `bash -c`, the argument immediately after that is taken as the command string to execute, and any further arguments are assigned to `$0`, `$1`, etc as it runs. So `bash -c echo hello` just runs `echo` with `$0` set to "hello". So it prints a blank line.

If you want the command to be executed as you expect, you need two layers of quotes and/or escapes, one to be applied and removed by the local shell and another to be applied and removed by the remote shell. Any of these will work:

```
# Single-quotes for local shell, double for remote
ssh ${myhost} 'bash -c "echo hello && echo hi"'

# Double-quotes for local shell, single for remote
ssh ${myhost} "bash -c 'echo hello && echo hi'"

 # Double-quotes for local shell, escaped doubles for remote
ssh ${myhost} "bash -c \"echo hello && echo hi\""

# Single-quotes for local shell, escaped characters for remote
ssh ${myhost} 'bash -c echo\ hello\ \&\&\ echo\ hi'
```

...and many more possibilities. Note that if the command string contains anything like variable references or command substitutions, you need to pay attention to whether you want them to expand on the local or remote computer, and make sure the quoting/escaping method you use accomplishes that.

BTW, in this case since you're running a command with `bash -c`, there's actually a *third* layer of parsing done by the shell invoked by `bash -c`. If that command has anything that needed quoting/escaping, keeping the levels straight will be even more complex.

Comment: While I forgot about the local processing of `"`, the real gem here is that the first argument to `bash -c` is assigned to `$0`, not `$1`. Totally explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The command that arrives to the server is : bash -c echo hello && echo hi

ie without quote

and if you run this cde locally, it produces the same output

If you want the good result

ssh mm 'bash -c "echo hello && echo hi"'

Comment: yes, those quotes do impact things, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Could also try using ";" as a separator

ssh ${myserver} "echo hello; echo hi"

```
testuser@mymac ~ % ssh ${myserver} "echo hello; echo hi"
hello
hi
testuser@mymac ~ %
```